Getting errors while using decodable extension in different module in Swift
I am facing issues while using init(from decoder: Decoder) in Model extension in different module.
I have model in Module 1 as below
public struct LabelModel {
    public var value: String?
}

And I have decodable extension in module 2
extension LabelModel: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case value
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        value = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .value) // error - 'self' used before 'self.init' call or assignment to 'self'
    } // error - 'self.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer
}

I am facing 2 errors while adding model extension with decodable in different module.
Any suggestion will be helpful for me.
Thanks in advance.

Side note: extension LabelModel: Decodable {} is sufficient.

@vadian Not if LabelModel is in another module...


put the decoded value into a local let,

create a LabelModel with that value as you normally would

set self to that LabelModel
 public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
     let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
     let value = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .value)
     // let someOtherProperty = ...
     // other properties (if any)...

     // assuming LabelModel has such a public initialiser...
     var label = LabelModel()
     // if it doesn't have a public initialiser, then this is not possible
     label.value = value
     // label.someOtherProperty = someOtherProperty
     // other properties (if any)...

     self = label
 }

If LabelModel has an initialiser that takes a value directly, you can just call that initialiser.
 let value = ...
 let label = LabelModel(value: value)
 self = label



